# Regex count adjacent pattern

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to count adjacent occurrences in a string. For example:

```
my $pattern = "aa";
my $string = "aaa";

my @matches  = $string =~ /($pattern)+/g;
my $c = @matches;

print "$c\n";
```

This prints 1 but I would like it to be 2 because there are actually 2 adjacent occurrences of "aa" in "aaa"

Thanks!

Comment: Tip: If you just want the count: `my $c = () = $string =~ /.../g;` or `my $c = 0; ++$c while $string =~ /.../g;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a zero-width lookahead instead of match:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $pattern = "(?=aa)";
my $string = "aaa";

my @matches = $string =~ /$pattern/g;
my $c = @matches;

print "$c\n"; 
//=> 2
```

`(?=aa)` is a positive lookahead that will assert true if it finds `aa` ahead of current position.

[Read more information about Look arounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)